# How I can earn money with bitcoin?

Tags: bitcoin-core, earnings

I need advices about the earning with bitcoin
I also need help with this

Answer (score 1):

Bitcoin is not a money machine.

It is a currency created on computers through "minning" using computational power.

Due to its deflationary feature i.e the having and the hard cap of 21 million coins.  The value will theoretically go up due to basic laws of supply & demand.

So if you want to make money from bitcoin.

The most straight forward options are;

a) Buy and hold BTC, then sell incase of a profit(if the price appreciates).

b) Invest in minning infrastructure and sell minned bitcoins on exchanges  to cover maintenance costs + profit

Answer (score 0):

you're question is not specific enough... 
It could be interpreted as "how do I get rich without doing much work". If this was not the intention, then 
I'd like to add the point, that you can start programming and get payed in bitcoins. There are several threads that capture this topic (requires some research here and in bitcointalk.org).